# How I can to delete a custom listview item in android?

Tags: android, listview

I have a custom list View:
i want to in my app ,with Clicking on a button ,delete a item list view

I don't Understand how edit a method in my class for delete 
a item custom list view...
please help me for write a method for delete item..
thanks you

java code is:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

String[] name;
String[] family;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    name=new String[]{"aaa","bbb","samad","yoset","hasan"};
    family=new String[]{"AAA","Ahamadi","Ahamadi","Ahamadi","Ahamadi"};

  ListView list=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);

    MyAdapter adapter=new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext());




   list.setAdapter(adapter);





}



private class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter
 {
LayoutInflater MyInflater;
public MyAdapter(Context context) 
{
    MyInflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
}




@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return name.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@SuppressLint("InflateParams")
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder X=new ViewHolder();
    View row=null;
Object user = getItem(position);
user.

    if(convertView==null)
    {
        convertView=MyInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,null);

        X.Name=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Text_name);
        X.Family=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Text_family);

        convertView.setTag(X);
    }

    else{

        X=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }


    X.Name.setText(name[position]);
    X.Family.setText(family[position]);



    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return convertView;
}


//-class Holder
public class ViewHolder
{

    TextView Name;
    TextView Family;
}


 }


}
```

I don't Understand how edit a method in my class for delete 
a item custom list view...
please help me for write a method for delete item..
thanks you

Comment: I would suggest you use an arraylist instead of array and on click of button just call remove function on array list and notifyDataSetChanged on Adapter.

Comment: you can check out something like this https://github.com/timroes/EnhancedListView

Answer (score 0):

```
Object item = adapter.getItem(position);

adapter.remove(item);

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: thank..but no exist method with name remove()...please help me

Answer (score 0):

You are extending BaseAdapter ,thats why you are not getting remove method, its available in ArrayAdapter,SimplerAdapter. Dont worry write your own remove method in your custom adapter -

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    name=new String[]{"aaa","bbb","samad","yoset","hasan"};
    family=new String[]{"AAA","Ahamadi","Ahamadi","Ahamadi","Ahamadi"};
    List<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(name));
    List<String> familyList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(family));

    ListView list=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);

    MyAdapter adapter=new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext());

    list.setAdapter(adapter);

}

private class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
LayoutInflater MyInflater;
public MyAdapter(Context context) 
{
    MyInflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
}


public void remove(int pos)
{
  nameList.remove(pos);
  familyList.remove(pos);

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return nameList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {

    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@SuppressLint("InflateParams")
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder X=new ViewHolder();
    View row=null;
Object user = getItem(position);


    if(convertView==null)
    {
        convertView=MyInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,null);

        X.Name=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Text_name);
        X.Family=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Text_family);

        convertView.setTag(X);
    }

    else{

        X=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }


    X.Name.setText(nameList.get(position));
    X.Family.setText(familyList.get(position));



    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return convertView;
}


//-class Holder
public class ViewHolder
{

    TextView Name;
    TextView Family;
}


 }
```

now to remove item use this code-

```
  ((MyAdapter)list.getAdapter()).remove(position);
  ((MyAdapter)list.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

and your adapter design is not so good, try to improve it. And use ArrayList for adapter instead of array, it is more flexible.

Don't forget to mark as correct , if it solved your problem.